# TP-LINK TL-WR42N router firmware update fail

Tags: linux, networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have TP-LINK tl-wr842n Ver 3.1 router. I updated my firmware to : https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr842nd#tl-wr842n_eu_hw_ver_31 Actual link what I downloaded and used for upgrade: https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr842n-v3-squashfs-factory.bin So my update finished and then It restarted, but then I couldn't access to adminpanel(default gateway 192.168.1.1) and I know it was before update 192.168.0.1. I tried all ip's but still I cant accsess to my router.

Wan and LAN LED's are blinking, I tried pulling out cables and disconnecting network card. Still cant access to router. Even installation(resource)-cd cant recognize my router

Can I somehow connect to buddy and restore firmware?

Comment: It sounds like you bricked the router.  Use the instructions for your router to unbrick the router, if there are no instructions it sadly means reversing your actions are not possible.  *The way I know its bricked is the fact the LEDs are blinking.*  You can confirm this is actually the case though by attempting to ssh into the router.

Comment: Does it gives you an IP address when connected to LAN ? (which would be a sign of DHCP service working)

Comment: DHCP is working, It gives me IP addresses

Comment: So which IP address does it give you? 192.168.1.x? Can you ping/mtr 192.168.1.1? Are you connecting to the correct LAN port? Blinking LEDs usually means everything works fine, there may just be confusion about the address. Though v3.1 seems new enough anything is possible. If all else fails, try restoring the original firmware via `tftp`, I've done this successfully for my WD841N.

Answer (score 0):

There is a failsafe Mode in openwrt. Usually you boot into it by pressing certain  hardware buttons during startup. You then can connect using fixed ips and check your config or flash firmware. But i doubt luci will work.

[Openwrt failsafe mode](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe)

Answer (score 0):

You tried the trunk version of openwrt, it does not contain luci(GUI of router) and there is no support of any versions except of trunk for your router. You can telnet or ssh to router and then install luci by following commands:

```
opkg update
opkg install luci
opkg install uhttpd
/etc/init.d/uhttpd start
/etc/init.d/uhttpd enable
```